# How to pass variables to view from controller in Laravel

Tags: php, view, laravel-4

When user place his order it redirects him to another page which check if he made his payment or no. Now The controller is ready and I need to initialize the box which make this and I need to took some variables.. I don't know how to implement this into payment.blade.php. This is what I tried and doesn't seems to work.

This is the controller

```
public function paymentView( $orderId, $userId ) {

    $order = Session::all();

    $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->first();

    if (!$order) {
        App::abort(404);
    }


    $userID         = $order['user_id'];                        
    $orderID        = $order['order_id'];           

    $options = array(
        ...
    );

    // Initialise Payment Class
    $box = new Cryptobox ($options);

    // coin name
    $coinName = $box->coin_name(); 

    // Successful Cryptocoin Payment received
    if ($box->is_paid()) 
    {
        if (!$box->is_confirmed()) {
            $message =  "Thank you for payment (payment #".$box->payment_id()."). Awaiting transaction/payment confirmation";
        }                                           
        else 
        { 

            if (!$box->is_processed())
            {

                $message = "Thank you for order (order #".$orderID.", payment #".$box->payment_id()."). We will send soon";

                $box->set_status_processed();  
            }
            else $message = "Thank you. Your order is in process"; // General message
        }
    }
    else $message = "This invoice has not been paid yet";

    $languages_list = display_language_box($def_language);

    return View::make('site.cart.payment', [
                'order' => $order,
    ]); 
}
```

Now I'm trying to put this in my view

```
@section('content')
  @foreach($order->getOrderData(true) as $productId => $item)
     <?php if (!$box->is_paid()) echo "<h2>Pay Invoice Now - </h2>"; else echo "<br><br>";  ?>

     <?php echo $box->display_cryptobox(true, 580, 230); ?>
  @endforeach
@endsection
```

When I run the page I've got error that `box` isn't defined.. How can I take this info in the view?

Comment: yy... exactly the same as you've added $order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way you've passed `$order` to the view. Replace the `return` at the bottom of you method with this return.

```
return View::make('site.cart.payment', [
    'order' => $order,
    'box' => $box
]);
```

The second argument passed to `View::make()` is an array of data that should be made available to the view.

Comment: The problem is in foreach but can't understand what and why